# Бесконечная анимация

Tags: javascript, анимация

Как сделать бесконечную анимацию на чистом JS?

Необходимо чтобы квадрат менял свои размеры от указанной величины, до 0 и в обратную сторону.

```js
var firstElem = document.getElementById("elemFirst");

function getSizeFirst(elem) {
  var i = getComputedStyle(elem).height.slice(0, -2);

  function changeSize() {
    if (i > 0) {
      --i;
      elem.style.height = i + "px";
      setTimeout(function() {
        changeSize();
      }, 0)
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
 
 changeSize();
}

getSizeFirst(firstElem);
```

```css
#elemFirst {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #223;
}
```

```html
<div id="elemFirst"></div>
```

Comment: Вас интерисует css3 или js? Если js то нужна ф-ция `window.setInterval` - и туда пишите любые действия, которые сделают цикл.

Comment: @nick_n_a, `Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать бесконечную анимация на чистом js?`. Если вы не заметили, то я и так использую `window.setInterval`, но мне не приходит в голову как правильно написать алгоритм. В место `window.setInterval` можно еще использовать `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: У вас путаница с setTimeout там где проще было бы  setInterval

Comment: @nick_n_a, прежде чем раздавать советы, ознакомьтесь с предметом. https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```js
var firstElem = document.getElementById("elemFirst");

function getSizeFirst(elem) {
  var i = getComputedStyle(elem).height.slice(0, -2);
  
  function sSize() {
    if(i > 0) {
      --i;
      elem.style.height = i + "px";
      setTimeout(function() {
        sSize();
      }, 0)
    } else {
      mSize();
    }
  }
  function mSize() {
    if(i < 50) {
      ++i;
      elem.style.height = i + "px";
      setTimeout(function() {
        mSize();
      }, 0)
    } else {
      sSize();
    }
  }
 
 sSize();
}

getSizeFirst(firstElem);
```

```css
#elemFirst {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #223;
}
```

```html
<div id="elemFirst"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй css:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #223;
  animation: size-anim 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes size-anim {
    0%   {   width:  0  ;   height:  0  ;   }
   50%   {   width: 50px;   height: 50px;   }
  100%   {   width:  0  ;   height:  0  ;   }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать бесконечную анимация на чистом js?`

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178988

Comment: За что минусуют ответ? анимация на css всегда лучше чем на js

Comment: @lazyproger, я четко дал понять, что меня интересует на чисто js, а не css, jquery и тому подобное. я прекрасно знаю как это делать с помощью `@keyframes`.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный а можете в двух словах ответить на вопрос, почему js?

Comment: @lazyproger, в некоторых случаях анимация на css не применима.

Comment: @Qwertiy, поищи дубликат, уже был вопрос подобный, только там в лог вроде бы выводилось не могу найти

Comment: @Grundy, если это такой случай, то должно быть понятно, почему он такой, иначе ответ бесполезен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ничего личного) я буду благодарен если найдете дубликат. у меня нет желания засорять глупыми вопросами ресурс.